# How do i connect my android app with git. I am new to git Please help me

Tags: android, git, github, version-control, gitlab

please tell me how can I add an android application to git and work on git like version control etc. And what is the use of pull and push etc

Answer (score 0):

Push term refers to upload local repository content to a central repository. It is an act of transfer commits from your local repo to central repo.

Git pull command is used to fetch and download content from a remote repository and immediately update in local repository.

Please gothrough the link [1](https://atlassian.com/git/tutorials/learn-git-with-bitbucket-cloud) It may helpful to you for Git learning.